# In a check-in/check-out syncronization setup, can a parent replica still be edited when child checked out?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, replication

In a check-in/check-out synchronization setup, can the parent replica geodatabase be edited while the child geodatabase is checked out and edited, and then when the child checks in their changes, have them reconciled against the parent changes?

I am trying to figure out what sync relation I can accomplish when limited to basic level license for the editing clients, but still allow the parent master to get changes while children are editing.  On that note, can a check-in/check-out have more than one child checked out at a time?

The main situation is that I am working with a small municipality who only have a Standard level license, but have three field crew tablets that need to be out in the field editing features simultaniously, the tablets connecting to an online version of the GDB at AmigoCloud.com which itself syncs back to the ESRI GDB.  But back in the office on the standard license I would like to continue working with the data while the field crews are out, and at end of day when they come back and sync I would like to sequentially sync each child with the parent and resolve any conflicts, but i wouldn't need to sync my changes to the tablets as my sync to the AmigoCloud child would migrate those edits.

So would the Standard license have to put out one child GDB, that child GDB is the one that syncs to AmigoCloud.com, and once all the field crews changes are into the AmigoCloud.com GDB that one is synced to the master and any conflicts are resolved, or with check-in/check-out is there no conflict resolution and one set of data is favoured over another?

I'd likely need to review the conflicts to settle them manually.  I guess after I am done syncing the AmigoCloud edits back to master GDB I would have to create a new child replica for AmigoCloud, so not sure this model would work given their sync.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.